# Recursive CTE query works on SQLiteSpy (not always) and fails on Python

Tags: python, sqlite, recursive-query

The following code creates a database with a few records, then executes a recursive query, then executes the same recursive query with a `UNION` operator.

If I run the code on Python 3.4.0 with sqlite 3.8.3.1 the first recursive query works, but the second fails.

If I run the same code inside [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) with sqlite 3.8.4.3 both the queries succeed.

If I invert the order of the `UNION` operands (simple query `UNION` recursive query instead of recursive query `UNION` simple query) then it fails also in SQLiteSpy.

In the [release notes of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) I didn't find anything that would affect this difference in the behavior.

How do I get the recursive query to work in Python?

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = db.cursor()

print('preparing stuff')
cur.executescript("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Parts;

CREATE TABLE Parts ( 
    Id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Desc     TEXT,
    ParentId INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (1,  'CEO',                  NULL);
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (2,  'VIP Sales',            1);
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (3,  'VIP Operations',       1);
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (4,  'Sales Manager Europe', 2);
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (5,  'Sales Manager USA',    2);
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (6,  'Sales Rep Europe 1',   4);
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (7,  'Sales Rep Europe 2',   4);
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (8,  'Sales Rep USA 1',      5);
INSERT INTO Parts VALUES (9,  'Sales Rep USA 2',      5);""")

print('executing simple query')
cur.executescript("""WITH RECURSIVE Cte (
    Level,
    Id,
    Desc,
    ParentId,
    ParentDesc
  ) AS (
    SELECT 0,
           Child.Id,
           Child.Desc,
           Parent.Id,
           Parent.Desc
      FROM Parts AS Child
           JOIN Parts AS Parent ON Child.ParentId = Parent.Id
     WHERE Child.Desc = 'Sales Rep USA 1'

     UNION ALL

    SELECT Cte.Level + 1,
           Child.Id,
           Child.Desc,
           Parent.Id,
           Parent.Desc
      FROM Parts as Child, Cte
           JOIN Parts AS Parent ON Child.ParentId = Parent.Id
     WHERE Child.Id = Cte.ParentId
)
SELECT ParentId,
       ParentDesc
  FROM Cte;""")

print('executing query with union')
cur.executescript("""WITH RECURSIVE Cte (
    Level,
    Id,
    Desc,
    ParentId,
    ParentDesc
  ) AS (
    SELECT 0,
           Child.Id,
           Child.Desc,
           Parent.Id,
           Parent.Desc
      FROM Parts AS Child
           JOIN Parts AS Parent ON Child.ParentId = Parent.Id
     WHERE Child.Desc = 'Sales Rep USA 1'

     UNION ALL

    SELECT Cte.Level + 1,
           Child.Id,
           Child.Desc,
           Parent.Id,
           Parent.Desc
      FROM Parts as Child, Cte
           JOIN Parts AS Parent ON Child.ParentId = Parent.Id
     WHERE Child.Id = Cte.ParentId
)
SELECT ParentId,
       ParentDesc
  FROM Cte

UNION ALL

SELECT Id,
       Desc
  FROM Parts
 WHERE Desc = 'Sales Rep USA 1';""")
```

Comment: Works on 3.8.6. You'll have to upgrade ...

Comment: @CL.: How do I upgrade sqlite? Do I need to install the latest version Python? Or is there a way to install another version of sqlite and tell Python to use it?

Comment: @CL. I upgraded Python from 3.4.0 to 3.4.1, but the sqlite version is still 3.8.3.1. I tried with `pip install --upgrade pysqlite`, but I get an error message about sphinx.

Comment: I guess you'd have to recompile Python, or try a more up-to-date library like [APSW](https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw).